# DB Connection Trouble, when starting muliple connections

Tags: database, windows-server, oracle-11g

I'm working on a Windows Server 2016 and want to connect to an Oracle 11gR2 DB. When I'm starting to connect, the Java Application works fine. But when a second Application(Python) starts the first Application freezes. They're not using the same Driver but connect to the same Scheme. The First application uses OJDBC compiled into the JAR and the Second application uses the SYSTEM ODBC Driver. I'm using the same Login for both. Can anyone explain why those applications affect themselves? Can a different Login solve this Problem?

Cheers
Kumar

Comment: Mods, I think this is more appropriate in StackOverflow or https://dba.stackexchange.com/